# How to use RxJS finalize in Angular to limit user clicks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How to use rxjs finalized in angular to limit user from clicking the save button multiple times and sending request multiple times.

Assume this call is triggered by a button click on our form. Many people still double-click on those buttons and we definitely want to prevent 2 calls being sent to our backend API.

My code is below. Thanks for any help.

## Code

```
save(): void {
    const create = this.requestFormService.createRequestData(this.form, this.respondents)
      .subscribe(
        (results: FeedbackRequest[]) => {
          this.hasBeenSubmitted = true;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.hasBeenSubmitted = false;
          this.handleInvalidFields(error, 'Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.');
          this.messageDialogService.show('Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.', true);
          create.unsubscribe();
        }
      );
  }
```

## HTML

```
<button [disabled]="form.invalid || (!duplicateMode && !form.dirty) || (!editMode) || hasBeenSubmitted"
        mat-raised-button *ngIf="form" (click)="save()" type="submit">
        <ng-container>
          <span>SAVE</span>
        </ng-container>
      </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `finalize`, it will be more straightforward to achieve the above logic by using the `take()` operator. As stated on the RxJS documentation for [take](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take),

> Emit provided number of values before completing.

```
save(): void {
  const create = this.requestFormService.createRequestData(this.form, this.respondents)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
    ).subscribe((results: FeedbackRequest[]) => {
      this.hasBeenSubmitted = true;
    }, (error) => {
      this.hasBeenSubmitted = false;
      this.handleInvalidFields(error, 'Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.');
        this.messageDialogService.show('Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.', true);
      create.unsubscribe();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: how does it limit the user from submitting multiple request ?

Comment: Because this will ensure that the user will only click it once while the request is pending

Comment: what is 1 in take ?

Comment: so this means that no matter how many time user sumit data will not be created until the request is done ?

Comment: Yep! That's right. It only takes in 1 emitted value, which is the first time when the user clicks it.

Comment: if the user clicks the button, the method will be called again and a new request will be sent again (unless some kind of caching system is in place in the function called). the take does make the unsubscribe call unnecessary though